# Bing Speech API - unexpected calls

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bing-speech

I have APS.NET Application and it is deployed on Azure.
Application calls Bing Speech API to recognize voice. (Client makes POST request and server calls Bing Speech API for every request).

It looks like this:

[image]

ONLY server calls Bing Speech API.

And now in Azure dashboard I see a lot of calls to Bing Speech API without requests to my server, and I don't know who or what it can be.
I regenerated Bing Speech API key but it didn't help.
Bing Speech quota is limited so it is big and expensive problem.

there are screenshots from dashboard:

[image]

[image]

Quota has been exceeded:

[image]

Thanks for any help and any advice!

Comment: ``a lot of calls to Bing Speech API without requests to my server, and I don't know who or what it can be.`` Would the Bing Speech API still be called if you stop your Azure app service or regenerate key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls Bing Speech API were... calls to getting new access Token.
So, it means gettings access token is billable.

I'm going to minimize gettings new tokens in my app to solve my problem.

Thanks.